# Division in phpexcel is not working (formula)

Tags: phpexcel

I wanted divide a cell with another cell but I got an error that says

> A PHP Error was encountered.
>   Severity: Notice. Message: Array to string conversion. Filename:
>   PHPExcel/Calculations.php. Line Number: 3010.

I only wanted to divide the value of `G23` by the value of `H21` and assign the result in `J23`.

Here's my code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J23', '=(G23/H21)');
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `'=(G23/H21)'` to `'=sum(G23/H21)'`